# Stumped finding a formula for a number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

First off, I'm not a math major, but a programmer by training. But this is a math question, not a programming question.

I am trying to find a formula for about 52 sequences recorded from watching how  stats of characters change in a certain mobile game, but none of the ways I tried could land a perfect fit.

Here are two such sequences:

Sequence 1: **0, 115, 229, 342, 453, 562, 670, 777, 882, 985, 1087, 1188, 1287, 1385,
1481, 1575, 1669, 1760, 1850, 1939, 2026, 2112, 2196, 2279, 2360, 2440, 2518,
2595, 2670, 2744, 2816, 2887, 2956, 3024, 3090, 3155, 3218, 3280, 3341, 3400**

Sequence 2: **0, 57, 114, 171, 226, 281, 335, 388, 441, 492, 543, 594, 643,
692, 740, 787, 834, 880, 925, 969, 1013, 1056, 1098, 1139, 1180, 1220, 1259,
1297, 1335, 1372, 1408, 1443, 1478, 1512, 1545, 1577, 1609, 1640, 1670, 1700**

Using sequence 1 as an example, suppose character C's HP is A at level 1, then his HP at level 2 onwards would be A+115, A+229, and so on up to A+3400 at level 40. For conciseness let's name this sequence f(x).

I first tried approximating the terms by scaling the sequences so that f(40)=1, which while showing a tendency that f(2) ~= 0.033 * f(40) for any of the 52 sequences I recorded, the numbers never align with each other.

Then I tried the differential route. Although the differences between terms in the sequence show a monotonic, linear decrease, simple linear interpolation of gaps in the sequence d(x) = f(x)-f(x-1) doesn't always work, with the actual observed value off by plus or minus 1 from my interpolations. Is extending this interpolation of d(x) beyond x=40 until d(x)=0 then try to find an antiderivative a viable approach?

Another property I saw, illustrated in the two sequences given, is if the end point of a different sequence g is exactly 1/2 that of sequence f, the terms of g can be represented exactly as:

g(L) = floor(1/2 * f(L))

This tells me there is rounding involved, but I can't determine at what stage, how many times, or what type ie. down? up? nearest?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're looking for here. Can you explain more clearly what it would mean to "land a perfect fit"?

Comment: You have a number 1669 in sequence 1. Any chance that's a typo and that it should be 1668?

Comment: @AustinWeaver From all the numbers I've logged I believe there is a formula behind these sequences that generates it. For a mobile game it's much more efficient to only specify minimum and maximum parameters, and calculate numbers in between, than to have a table of them all. I am trying to find that formula that, with rounding factored in, produce the same sequences as I've recorded.

Comment: @Keepthesemind That is not a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but here are my thoughts:

The data looks very nearly linear, but is not quite. It is very linear at first before slowly tapering downward later in the sequence.

The data's differences are quasi-regular: they follow patterns sometimes, but not consistently.

Using wolfram alpha to plot these sets of data yielded the following graphs:

[image]

[image]

Knowing that the first differences of these sets of data are very nearly linear, we could easily model the numbers and extrapolate or interpolate using a quadratic regression. Unfortunately, these values are not likely to be exact.

All this to say, you're going to have a very hard time finding a formula to calculate these exact values.

Answer (score 1):

If you fit a quadratic the $R^2$ coefficient is $0.99999994$.
$$
f(x)=[-0.744524891x^2 + 116.2119866975x - 0.2452090592]
$$
where $[\cdot]$ means round to nearest integer and $f(0)=0, f(1)=115, \cdots$. 
The coefficients of this quadratic may have been found numerically so they could just be arbitrary. You could try a similar process for the 51 other functions.